# Macro replace itself using undesired braces

Tags: c++, c++17

I have problems with macros, since they are being replaced with braces.

Since I will need to compile for different Operative Systems [WINDOWS, OSX, ANDROID, iOS], I'm trying to use typedef for the basic C++ types, to replace them easily and test performances.

Since I'm doing lots of static_cast, I thought I could use a macro to do it only when its need (CPU is critical on my software). So in this way, the static_cast will be only performed when the types are different, instead doing weird things like this:

```
const int tv = 8;
const int tvc = static_cast<int>(8);
```

So, if FORCE_USE32 is enabled or not, it would choose the best version for it

So Visual Studio 2017 using default compiler gives me an error when I do some things like this:

```
#ifndef FORCE_USE32
#define FORCE_USE32 0
#endif


#if FORCE_USE32
   typedef int s08;
    #define Cs08(v) {v}
#else
   typedef char s08;
   #define Cs08(v) {static_cast<s08>(v)}
#endif

// this line give me an error because Cs08 is replaced by {static_cast<s08>(1)} instead just static_cast<s08>(1)
std::array<s08, 3> myArray{Cs08(1), 0, 0};
```

I know I could solve easily creating a variable before I do the array, something like this

```
const s08 tempVar = Cs08(1);
std::array<s08, 3> myArray{tempVar, 0, 0};
```

But I do not understand the reason, and I want to keep my code as clean as possible. Is there any way to include the macro inside the array definition?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but if you #define something with {} then that's what's you get on expansion. If you don't want that then you shouldn't inlcude the parentheses? Can you not just `#define Cs08(v) static_cast<s08>(v)` ? Or use a function instead of a macro?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Indeed, that was the right answer. I think my teacher told me that a Macro definition should be always inside braces... maybe I understood him in the wrong way.

Comment: Teacher meant `()` braces.

Comment: always use the main language tag

Comment: Minor point: if a macro has not been defined, it is treated as having the value 0 when it's used. So that initial `ifndef FORCE_USE32` etc. isn't really needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to solve a non-problem

```
const int tvc = static_cast<int>(8);
```

Will not use any CPU cycles here. How dumb do you think compilers are nowadays? Even with no optimizations the above cast is a no-op (no operation). There won't be any additional instructions generated for the cast.

```
auto test(int a) -> int
{
    return a;
}

auto test_cast(int a) -> int
{
    return static_cast<int>(a);
}
```

With no optimization enabled the two functions generate **identical** code:

```
test(int):                               # @test(int)
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], edi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
        pop     rbp
        ret
test_cast(int):                          # @test_cast(int)
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], edi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

With `-O3` they get:

```
test(int):                               # @test(int)
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
test_cast(int):                          # @test_cast(int)
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

---

Coming back to how smart the compilers (actually the optimization algorithms) are, with optimizations enabled a compiler can do crazy crazy things, like loop unrolling, converting a recursive function to an iterative one, removing entire redundant code and on and on and on. What you are doing is premature optimization. If your code is performance critical then you need a decent understanding of assembly, compiler optimizations and system architecture. And then you don't just blindly optimize what you think is slow. You write code for readability first and then you profile.

---

Answering your macro problem: just remove the `{}` from the macro:

```
#define Cs08(v) v
#define Cs08(v) static_cast<s08>(v)
```

Comment: Thank you for the extended reply. I will learn the basic of assembly right now. All the best!